# JSON object format is not valid at server when sending using JAVA POST method

Tags: json

I am creating a JSON object like below-

```
    JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    try {
          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Log.d("buildReportAsString",
                        "cursor.getString(3)" + cursor.getString(3));
                String data = cursor.getString(3);
                if (data != null) {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);

                    arr.put(obj);
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        Log.d("buildReportAsString", "arr is " + arr);
        jsonData.put("events", arr);

    } catch (JSONException je) {
        Log.d(TAG, "JSON Exception is" + je);
    }
```

I print it and it seems in correct json format but when i see it at server, json format          is not valid as all commas disappears.
Client side -

```
    {
"events":[
{
    "timestamp":1404819090958,
    "minBatchSize":50,
    "freq":15
},
{
    "timestamp":1404819089917,
    "value":0.2175,
    "topProcess":"system"
},
{
    "timestamp":1404819091157,
    "CacheMemory":130876,
    "SwapMemory":0
}

        ]
}
```

But after i see this json data on server, all commas disappear and  it looks like   Jbelow-

```
    {
    "events": [
        {
"timestamp": 1404823898222
"minBatchSize": 100
"freq": 168
}
{
"value": 0.155
"timestamp": 1404824016366
 "topProcess": "kthreadd"
    "topProcessLoad": 0

    }
    ]
    }
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong? It is device side i need to do something before     sending JSON object? I am using POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check content type of you post data ?

It should be of type

> "application/json"